# Pandas inserting values to new column using pandas apply/map/Applymap

Tags: python, pandas, analytics, data-analysis

The following is the dataframe,

```
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
2  3  5
3  4  6
4  5  7
5  6  8
6  7  9
```

I want to add a new column, call it `sum` which takes the sum of it's respective row values.

**Expected output**

```
   a  b  sum
0  1  3   4
1  2  4   6
2  3  5   8
3  4  6   10
4  5  7   12
5  6  8   14
6  7  9   16
```

How to achieve this using pandas `map`, `apply`, `Applymap` functions?

**My Code**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
    'b': [3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
})

def sum(df):
    return df['a']+df['b']

# Methods I tried
df['sum'] = df.apply(sum(df))
df['sum']=df[['a',"b"]].map(sum)
df['sum'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['a'] + x['b'])
```

#### Note: This is just a dummy code. The original code has a function which returns different output for each individual rows and it ain't as simple as applying sum function. So I request you to make a custom `sum` function and implement those methods, so that I'll learn and apply the same to my code.

Comment: can you post the code of what did you made so far and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Sure, just a sec

Comment: This is just a dummy code. The original ain't as simple as performing a sum function.

Comment: This is not a `machine-learning` question, please remove the tag.

Comment: Actually, in original code, there's a function which returns different output for each individual rows and it ain't as simple as applying sum function.

Comment: @AdarshWase I request you to make a custom `sum` function and implement those methods, so that I'll learn and apply the same to my code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the pandas `sum` function like below:

```
    import pandas as pd
    
    df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], "b": [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]})
    
    df["sum"] = df.sum(axis=1)

    print(df)
```

And if you have to use lambda with apply you can try:

```
import pandas as pd

def add(a, b):
    return a + b

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
    'b': [3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
})

df['sum'] = df.apply(lambda row : add(row['a'], row['b']), axis = 1)

print(df)
```